# How to use the Size or Move function in Windows task bar

Tags: windows

In the task bar, you can hover and right-click something and it will show Restore, Move, Size, Minimize, Maximize and Close Alt+F4. I tried to use the Size or Move but I cannot use it. When I click it, the cursor becomes a plus with arrows but I am unable to resize or move.

Note that somehow the window that I’m trying to use the Size or Move is hidden to an inaccessible place and it seems to be sized to the smallest size as possible.

Another note is that I’m able to maximize it but after clicking restore, it will again become small and goes to inaccessible place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to use the Size or Move but I cannot use it. When I click it, the cursor becomes a plus with arrows but I am unable to resize or move.

After selecting either the Size or Move options from a window menu, you need to press one of the arrow keys on your keyboard. Then, you can either continue using the keyboard, or you can use your mouse.

> I’m able to maximize it but after clicking restore, it will again become small and goes to inaccessible place.

That's normal. The operating system actually tracks *three* different states/sizes for windows: minimized, normal/restored, and maximized. When you maximize the window, it changes the size on the screen, but doesn't overwrite the internal information about its "normal/restored" size. Therefore, when you restore a maximized window, it goes back to its previous size, before it was maximized.

If you use the Size and/or Move options to control the window when it is in its "normal/restored" state, that will overwrite the window's normal/restored state.

Comment: Wow, so it needs to be the arrow keys. Thank you.